# Whatsapp link on products in android?

Tags: android

For the android Apps, is it possible to have a Whatsapp link on products? Once link it would send a message to my mobile number through whatsapp. Please advice.

Comment: Yes it is. Add a hyperlink like: whatsapp:yourtextorurlgoeshere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you want Branch link

1. for that you might wanna use branch library, try this link 
   [follow the inetegration given by them](http://branch.io)

Comment: thank you that's what i wanted :) branch works like a charm :D

Comment: i am happy it helped :)